# How can I build and run my Ionic-Cordova Project

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I get this error when I try build or run my Ionic project:

```
      ionic cordova run android
      cordova.cmd platform add android --save
      Using cordova-fetch for cordova-android@^12.0.0
      Adding android project...
      Unhandled error. ('createPlatform is not callable from the android 
      project API.')
      ng.cmd run app:ionic-cordova-build --platform=android
      Error: Unknown argument: platform
      [ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess ng.

      ng.cmd run app:ionic-cordova-build --platform=android exited with 
      exit
      code 1.

      Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more
      information.
```

[Platform folder is empty]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/qosGu.png)

My cordova and ionic versions are up to date. I did remove and re-added the platform android (though it does't appear in platforms folder).